# Difference between using `--save` and without it when using typings

Tags: typescript, angular, typescript-typings

I am using [TypeScript Definition Manager version 1.0](https://github.com/typings/typings).

I read the [Commands document](https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/commands.md).

But still not clear about the difference between using `--save` and without it.

For example,

```
typings install dt~aws-sdk --global
typings install dt~aws-sdk --global --save
```

I tried both, but seems like they are doing same thing.

Does **typings** use `--save` by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got help from @unional, and thanks!

When use `--save`, it will add info into **typings.json** file.